# "TypeError: this is undefined" while accessing private metod

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

In an Ionic component I made use of the amazing `<ion-virtual-scroll>` tag. Amazing with the header function in order to split items in the list. Now, seperating this code, I extracted parts of it into the private funtion `sameGroup`. Though that returns `TypeError: this is undefined` when I want to call it from the `myHeaderFn` function. Why?

(Yes, I know, I easily could plug that function code into the `myHeaderFn`. But that is not the questions.)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stash',
  templateUrl: './stash.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stash.page.scss'],
})
export class StashPage implements OnInit {

  public translations: Translation[];

  constructor(private translationService: TranslationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.translations = this.translationService.getAllTranslationsSorted('de', 'ar');
  }

  myHeaderFn(record, recordIndex, records) {
    if (**this.sameGroup(recordIndex, records)**) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return record['term'].substring(0, 1);
    }
  }

  private sameGroup(i, records) {
    if (i === 0) {
      return false;
    } else {
      const prevRecInitLet = records[i - 1]['term'].substring(0, 1);
      const currRecInitLet = records[i]['term'].substring(0, 1);
      return prevRecInitLet === currRecInitLet ? true : false;
    }
  }

}
```

The `myHeaderFn` is invoked by the ionic component `ion-virtual-scroll`.

```
 <ion-virtual-scroll [items]="translations" [headerFn]="myHeaderFn">
        <ion-item-divider *virtualHeader="let header">
            {{ header }}
        </ion-item-divider>

        <!-- need to wrap this into the div, so that *virtualItem is not part of the component -->
        <div *virtualItem="let trans">
            <!-- translation (not translations) referes to the model of the component -->
            <app-transitem [translation]=trans></app-transitem>
        </div>

    </ion-virtual-scroll>
```

Comment: how do you call `myHeaderFn`? You are not showing that.

Comment: @AJT82 it's triggered by ion-virtual-scroll

Comment: Can you call `sameGroup` even if it is not marked private??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the arrow function.

```
  myHeaderFn = (record, recordIndex, records) => {
    if (this.sameGroup(recordIndex, records)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return record['term'].substring(0, 1);
    }
  }
```

> Arrow functions do not have their own this value. The value of this inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope.

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/

Comment: Thans. But why is that? What is the anatomy behind it?

Comment: @Hsuan Lee. Check this stackblitz example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdqlst

Comment: @brk Is there anything unusual?